# HTML, CSS, Bootstrap - Two columns with centering

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a little website that should have two columns, and each column should have its content centered.

However, I have noticed that the columns will follow the height of each other, and not act as individual columns. E.g. whenever I add content to one of the columns, the content of the other column will be moved to fit the height of that column.

In the JSFiddle, you can see that the "Hello" on the right side is not completely centered; it has been moved up to stand in line with the first of three "Hello"'s on the left side. I would like it so, that whenever I add content to one column, it doesn't affect the other - so the "Hello" on the right side should ideally stay completely centered.

`JSFiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/goupb2ch/1/

I have worked on this for quite a while now. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use bootstrap 4 and make use of flex-box? Flexbox makes your wishes come true!

Comment: @Randy Thanks for the input. I might have to do that if I don't get any answers. I just started with 3.3.7. because it's the latest stable release

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is pretty stable at the moment. 3.3.7 will quickly be replaced after it is released for new projects I think, so it would not hurt to learn what flex-box does and why. If you read up on flex-box questions, you will find your own question answered a few times with complex code or simple flexbox solutions.

Comment: @Randy I will certainly do that, sounds like a very helpful tool. Cheers man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using flexbox to solve your problem: in this case far less code is required.

https://jsfiddle.net/upwgk2u4/

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.container > div {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this answer is in no way related to Bootstrap. `display: flex` is a CSS thing, not a Bootstrap thing.

Comment: @thesystem Flexbox is not restricted to bootstrap 4, it is just a CSS rule. Flexbox is implemented in Bootstrap 4 and not implemented in Bootstrap 3, but you can always extend the CSS with your own rules like he did and use flexbox. Keep in mind though, that flex-box is not supported by older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use what's already in Bootstrap 4? **No extra CSS** is needed.

https://www.codeply.com/go/0zwGz83Cbw

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <p>Hello</p>
            <p>Hello</p>
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center text-center">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```